# Expandable notification in lower android version

Tags: android, notifications

I am writing a sample application, a part of it contains notification.

I have written notification code for both Jellbean (expandable notification using the class 
"Notification.InboxStyle") and lower  version separately and put it inside version check condition as follows

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLYBEAN){

    notificationForJBVersion()
}
esle{
    notificationForLowerVersion()
}


 notificationForJBVersion(){

     InboxStyle inbox = new Notification.InboxStyle(............)
}
```

Application is running as expected, it executes notificationForJBVersion() for JB and notificationForLowerVersion() for lower version

But when I observed the Log I can see one dalvik error in older version  while loading the app ( not while running ) 
Error says it couldn't create the object of Notification$InboxStyle for the method 
notificationForJBVersion()

I am surprised , lower version doest use the method notificationForJBVersion(). so why it shows the error in notificationForJBVersion()?????

I suppose the error is due to following reason
While loading the app, dalvik creates the instance of all classes mentioned in app with out considering version, since the app creates the instance of Notification.InboxStyle which is not there in lower version, it throws error?? Am I correct???

if so , Is there any way to suppress this error ? or is it a known behaviour that we dont need to handle.. Please provide some inputs

Thanks
Vineesh

Answer (score 0):

> so why it shows the error in notificationForJBVersion()?????

That should be a warning, not an error. Dalvik reports warnings for all unresolved symbols at the time the class is loaded. It only throws an actual error, with a stack trace, if you try *executing* the line that contains the unresolved symbol.

> I suppose the error is due to following reason While loading the app, dalvik creates the instance of all classes mentioned in app with out considering version, since the app creates the instance of Notification.InboxStyle which is not there in lower version, it throws error?? Am I correct???

No.

> or is it a known behaviour that we dont need to handle

It is a known behavior that you do not need to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it was error not warning. Do you think this error will be shown for all objects whose class is not supported by target version.

Comment: @Vineesh: "it was error not warning" -- you are welcome to demonstrate that by posting the LogCat entries. "Do you think this error will be shown for all objects whose class is not supported by target version" -- as I wrote in my answer, Dalvik reports warnings for all unresolved symbols at the time the class is loaded. This will include references to classes, methods, static data members, and the like that are not recognized. However, these are warnings, not errors. They do not affect the user, and they do not indicate a problem with your app.

Comment: 05-25 07:48:21.236: D/dalvikvm(555): GC_CONCURRENT freed 512K, 4% free 15031K/15623K, paused 12ms+16ms
05-25 07:48:23.686: E/dalvikvm(555): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$InboxStyle', referenced from method com.sample.notification$1.notificationForJBVersion
05-25 07:48:23.686: W/dalvikvm(555): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 35 (Landroid/app/Notification$InboxStyle;) in Lcom/sample/notification$1;
05-25 07:48:23.696: D/dalvikvm(555): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000

Comment: @ CommonsWare: I Would like to know, do I have to worry about this error? or it is an expected error ,don't need to handle ?

Comment: @Vineesh: It is not something that you need to worry about.